Multiplication of surreal ordinals
I know the definition of addition of surreal numbers is

$x+y=\{x^L+y,x+y^L|x^R+y,x+y^R\}$

Since $x=\{\text{all ordinals less than }x|\}$, we can define surreal ordinal addition (which is commutative unlike normal ordinal addition) as
$$x+y=\{x^L+y,x+y^L|\}$$
The definition of multiplication of surreal numbers is

$xy=\{x^Ly+xy^L-x^Ly^L,x^Ry+xy^R-x^Ry^R|x^Ly+xy^R-x^Ly^R,x^Ry+xy^L-x^Ry^L\}$

Since $x=\{\text{all ordinals less than }x|\}$, we can define surreal ordinal multiplication (which is commutative unlike normal ordinal multiplication) as
$$xy=\{x^Ly+xy^L-x^Ly^L|\}$$
but this definition is a bit unsatisfying as it involves ordinal subtraction.
Question: Is there a recursive definition of surreal ordinal multiplication that only uses addition (of any two ordinals) and multiplication (of smaller ordinal pairs where $(a,b)<(c,d)$ iff $a\le c$ and $b\le d$ and $a<c\lor b<d$) without using subtraction? I'm okay if the definition is different for limit and successor ordinals.
My progress so far:
When $x=0$ or $y=0$, $xy=0$.
When left is successor, we have $(x+1)y=xy+y$.
When right is successor, we have $x(y+1)=xy+x$.
The only remaining case is when both $x$ and $y$ are non-zero limit ordinals.

Does this have a source?

Book is "On Numbers and Games".

To confirm, you'd like a proof or disproof that you can have such an expression in terms of the options like that? Or are other expressions that involve only sums and products but which don't involve taking all the options of the factors fair game?

A good expression is a definition where only sums (of any ordinals) and products of smaller ordinals are allowed. A random example (not actually the product): ${x+xy^L,x^Ly,x^L+y^L|}+{x+y^L,x^L+y}$

You have a typo in the definition of multiplication of surreal numbers, a "$y$" is missing.

@jjagmath I fixed it.

Here $0$ is not a limit ordinal or a successor ordinal.
If I am allowed to add one more recursive definition, I can do this:
$$\omega^x=\{0,r\omega^{x^L}|\}\text{ where $r$ ranges over all finite ordinals}$$
$$\omega^x=\{r\omega^{x^L}|\}\text{ if $x$ is non-zero and where $r$ ranges over all finite ordinals}$$
I have a recursive definition for all ordinals:
Case $1$: $x$ and $y$ are not both limits. I have a definition provided in my problem statement.
Case $2$: $x$ and $y$ are both limits.
Case $2.1$: When $x=\alpha+\beta$ with $\alpha<x$ and $\beta<x$ then $xy=\alpha y+\beta y$.
Case $2.2$: When $y=\alpha+\beta$ with $\alpha<y$ and $\beta<y$ then $xy=x\alpha+x\beta$.
Case $2.3$: When $x$ and $y$ are limit ordinals that are not the sum of smaller ordinals, it must be the case that $x=\omega^\alpha$ and $y=\omega^\beta$ for non-zero ordinals $\alpha$ and $\beta$.
Then $xy=\omega^\alpha\omega^\beta=\omega^{\alpha+\beta}=\{0,r\omega^{(\alpha+\beta)^L}|\}=\{0,r\omega^{\alpha^L+\beta},r\omega^{\alpha+\beta^L}|\}=\{0,r\omega^{\alpha^L}\omega^\beta,r\omega^\alpha\omega^{\beta^L}|\}$.
We have $r\omega^{\alpha^L}<\omega^\alpha$ and $r\omega^{\beta^L}<\omega^\beta$. So we can get $xy=\{0,(r\omega^{\alpha^L})\omega^\beta,(r\omega^{\beta^L})\omega^\alpha|\}=\{0,(r\omega^{\alpha^L})y,(r\omega^{\beta^L})x|\}\\=\{(r\omega^{\alpha^L})y,(r\omega^{\beta^L})x|\}=\{0,x^Ly,xy^L|\}\text{ since }\{r\omega^{\alpha^L}|\}=\omega^\alpha=x\text{ and }\{r\omega^{\beta^L}|\}=\omega^\beta=y.$

@IZukaI I edited it. Do you understand better?

@IZukaI To see that a limit ordinal that is not the sum of smaller ordinals, you can express it as a finite sum of powers of $\omega$. This is known as Cantor normal form.
